# Check if string within strings in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pretty simple pandas DataFrame and I want to select the portion of the DataFrame that has data within a column that contains within it another string

So if this is my DataFrame and I want those columns that contain `some` within the `Loc` column how can this be done?

```
             Loc 
0      'something'  
1      'nothing'
```

I tried two things:

```
df['some' in df['Loc']]
df[df.Loc.contains('some')]
```

But neither solution works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `contains`, one of the string accessor methods.

```
>>> df['Loc'].str.contains('some')
0     True
1    False
Name: Loc, dtype: bool
```

One would then use boolean indexing on the result to select the relevant rows of your dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df['Loc'].str.contains('some')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using replace , a fun way

```
df[df.Loc.replace({'some':np.nan},regex=True).isnull()]
Out[787]: 
           Loc
0  'something'
```

Update since Alex mention it in comment

```
df[df.Loc.apply(lambda x : 'some' in x)]
Out[801]: 
           Loc
0  'something'
```

Comment: That captures a lot of false positives.  Anything that does not convert to a string in the column would become NaN, which then gets captured by your `.isnull()` selection.

Comment: Still the same issue with `df['Loc'] = ['something', 'nothing', 55, None]`. Try `lambda x : True if isinstance(x, (str, unicode)) and 'some' in x else False`

Comment: @Alexander `df[df.Loc.astype(str).apply(lambda x : 'some' in x)]`, If we are talking about the mixtype